# Can't change the bottom margin

Tags: spacing, margins

Here's my code. I want the `pdf` to be one single page, but I can't change the `bottom margin`. If anyone can help that would be very helpful.

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}

 \usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[bottom =1 mm]{geometry}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}

% Margins
\topmargin=-1.25in
\evensidemargin=0in
\oddsidemargin=0in
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=9.0in
\headsep=0.25in


\title{ \textbf{Projects and Research Experiences}}
\author{Partha Sarathi Ghosh }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle  
1. \textbf{December 2017, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds:} In the winter of 2017 I did a reading project in Smooth manifolds and their properties under Prof. Kingshook Biswas at ISI Kolkata.\\

\vspace{0.80 mm}
2. \textbf{June-July 2018, Iwasawa Decomposition of $SL_2(\mathbb{R}):$} In the summer of 2018 I joined a discussion group in Topology at IISER Kolkata under Prof. Somnath Basu. Besides taking active part in the weekly discussions I worked on Iwasawa Decomposition of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and using it studied its topological properties and proved that any continuous Lie group homomorphism from $SL_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^*$ must be trivial. The project report can be found \href{https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bz9FVMMLoH6MwxtHLpVGdAACupQv6BWv/view?usp=sharing}{here}.\\

\vspace{0.80 mm}
3. \textbf{December 2018, Classification of Compact Surfaces:} In the winter of 2018 I did a reading project on Classification of Compact Surfaces under Prof. Samik Basu at ISI Kolkata. We proved the classification results for compact $2$-manifolds (both orientable and non-orientable) using triangulation and surgery on surfaces.\\

\vspace{0.80 mm}
4. \textbf{May-June 2019 (VSRP), Introduction to Riemann Surfaces:} In the summer of 2019 I went to TIFR, Mumbai as a VSRP( Visiting Students' Research Programme) student. I learnt basics of Complex Geometry and studied some amount of Riemann Surface Theory under the guidance of Prof. A.J. Parameswaran. I followed mainly R Narasimhan's \textit{Compact Riemann Surfaces}. Besides that I got to attend regular talks and seminars at TIFR and was introduced to many new areas of research in mathematics. The project report can be found \href{https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XolSZM_6NHg972-CPDRDmqg1wC3ciiM8}{here}.\\

\vspace{0.80 mm}
5. \textbf{July 2019, AIS on Riemannian Geometry:} In the summer of 2019 I attended an AIS(Advanced Instructional Schools) on Riemannian Geometry at IISc, Bangalore. Here I learnt the basic theory of Kähler Geometry and was introduced to some recent progress in research in related areas. I also got to see many interesting angles of Riemannian Geometry and Complex Geometry and a sketch of Yau’s proof of the Calabi conjecture for Kahler-Einstein metrics for negative first Chern class. \\

\vspace{0.80 mm}
6. \textbf{Master's Project, Compact Riemann Surfaces:}\\ Supervisor: {Dr.Kingshook Biswas} (Associate professor, Statistics and Mathematics Unit,ISI Kolkata) Here we study Compact Riemann Surfaces using analytical tools. We cover the following topics in this semester: Almost Complex structure on a Riemann Surface, $\bar{\partial}$-equation and Dolbeault lemma, Sheaves and sheaf cohomology, Leray's theorem, Short exact sequences of sheaves and long exact sequence in cohomology, Dolbeault theorem, de Rham theorem, Hodge theorem, finite dimensionality of cohomology groups, Riemann-Roch theorem and its applications, Embedding into Projective Space via ample divisors, Serre duality theorem, Mittag-Leffler problem for meromorphic functions and 1-forms with prescribed principal parts, Harmonic Forms on Riemann Surfaces, Riemann Bilinear Relations, Abel's Theorem and Jacobi Inversion Problem. The project report can be found \href{https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QN1YtA9lfaFM4Q7YGPdputF0EzX2nLSl/view?usp=sharing}{here}.


\end{document}
```

Comment: You use a package to change the page geometry and margins easily, and a few lines later... you overwrite it all with base TeX commands that you shouldn't use.

Comment: You should set all the page geometry using [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry), period.

Comment: Thanks it's solved now.